# Max Passcode Redemption

Tags: ingress

Since passcodes are no longer unlimited use, I want to know how many of my closest clan members I can share a newly deciphered passcode with before it returns `ALREADY_REDEEMED`.

Niantic has stated in forums that there is now a max value (it is not time-based), so I want to know if anyone has figured out the number.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer with precision to this answer, but we can assume the limit is based on the number of people redeeming the code.

[Official response from Niantic support](http://decodeingress.me/2012/11/29/ingress-passcodes-change/):

> Hello, 
>   Passcodes may only be used a certain number of times
>   collectively by all users before they are no longer valid. If the
>   passcode you have is no longer working, it means that limit has been
>   reached, and the passcode may no longer be used.
>   - NianticOpsBacon

Some tests made by users (put the code in a special page and count the visitors until code is redeemed) talk about a number around 1000-2000 uses.